# Saving Base64 Buffer as an image to the Disk

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

in a `Node.js` app, i send an image via `Socket.io` to the server. in the server, i get it like this and i wanted to save it on the disk. it save's but i cant open that image and image viewer says it's damaged! file size is correct but i can't open it. is there anything that i miss in the code?

```
    socket.on('newImage', function (data) {
       var img = data.image;
       var coded_img = new Buffer(img, 'base64');

       fs.writeFile("out.png", coded_img,'base64', function(err) {
             if (err) throw err;
             console.log('File saved.')
       });
    });
```

Comment: try removing  `base64` from `writeFile` since data is a buffer.

Comment: @hassansin node ignores the encoding if the data to be written is already a Buffer instance.

Comment: Did you verify the contents of `img`? What does it contain?

Comment: @mscdex, good catch!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it, With this function, i recovered main image data:

```
decodeBase64Image = function(dataString) {
    var matches = dataString.match(/^data:([A-Za-z-+\/]+);base64,(.+)$/),
        response = {};

    if (matches.length !== 3) {
        return new Error('Invalid input string');
    }

    response.type = matches[1];
    response.data = new Buffer(matches[2], 'base64');

    return response;
};
```

Comment: `.match()` returns `null` when it doesn't match FYI. If it's not null, the length will always be `3`.